# Iphone 3GS Error

Tags: iphone

i have a problem on  iphone 3GS.When application installed on phone that time debugger shows various error.These error occured on  SDK 3.0
ERROR:-

/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS3.0.sdk/usr/lib/dyld' has changed; re-reading symbols.
gdb-arm-apple-darwin(3064) malloc: *** mmap(size=3443003392) failed (error code=12)
*** error: can't allocate region
*** set a breakpoint in malloc_error_break to debug
gdb stack crawl at point of internal error:

[ 1 ] /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/usr/libexec/gdb/gdb-arm-apple-darwin (xstrvprintf+0x0) [0x124bb5]

SourceCache/gdb/gdb-1119/src/gdb/utils.c:1179: internal-error: virtual memory exhausted.
A problem internal to GDB has been detected,
further debugging may prove unreliable.

The Debugger has exited with status 1.The Debugger has exited with status 1.

I can't understand these error. Pls help me.

Comment: Can you post some code? Is this is a programming question?

Answer (score 3):

You tried to allocate a massive chunk of memory, and since that's more memory than is available, your app died.